# debug Blender Python in Eclipse and PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, blender

How do you go about debug Blender Python in Eclipse and PyDev?

What I have tried is:

http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/LuxBlend25_Debugging_with_eclipse

http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3914&sid=717a127d12596f89e4aea0c54938ef80

But non of then seams to work?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I setup debug, which is slight different but based on the lux-render tutorial.

First, create the a .py file, lets call it debug.py, which will contain a function which we will call later to setup debugging. Put this file in the same folder as the main `__init__.py` of your module. As per the lux-renderer tutorial, add the following code, updating PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR.

```
import sys

def startdebug():
    try:
        # set the PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR correctly before using the debugger
        PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR = 'C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.5.0.2012040618\pysrc'

        # test if PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR already in sys.path, otherwise append it
        if sys.path.count(PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR) < 1:
            sys.path.append(PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR)

        # import pydevd module
        import pydevd

        # set debugging enabled
        pydevd.settrace(None, True, True, 5678, False, False)
    except:
        pass
```

When setting the PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR ensure you point it to the org.python.pydev.debug_xxxxx. There is another folder similiar to this. To ensure you have the correct folder it will contain a /pysrc folder.

Now in your main `__init__.py`, this must come before any other import statements to work correctly. Add the following directly under the bl_info section, as strangely blender parses this itself.

```
DEBUGGING = True
if(DEBUGGING):
    import debug
    debug.startdebug()
```

Having it here will avoids adding per file traces like the lux-render tutorial.

1. Add some breakpoint to the version in the add-ons folder,
2. Switch to the debug perspective,
3. Start Eclipses debug server,
4. Start blender
5. Run the script and it will hit the breakpoint.

The common problems I find people encounter:

- pointing the path to the wrong pydev debug folder, ensure that there is a /pysrc folder
- When Pydev updates, update the PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR as the debug_xxxxx will have change
- not having eclipse server running,
- setting breakpoints on a local copy of the files instead of the version in the blender add-on directory
- saving the script does not mean that blender will reload it, use imp, disable/renable the add-on or restart Blender.

Answer (score 3):

There is very good e-book written by  Witold Jaworski about Blender add-on programming. It includes chapters with step by step instructions how to setup Eclipce with PyDev to debug Blender add-ons.
[Programming Add-ons for Blender 2.5](http://airplanes3d.net/pydev-000_e.xml)

Comment: I am on a Mac computer. I know this one, it only works when you are NOT starting Blender from the terminal(meaning starting the Blender.app it works). Therefore, you dont get any console information? Also the Debug Console is not working in Eclipse(No active debugger or evaluation error) Any idea?

Comment: You need to run the debugger against the version in the module folder. The debugger runs against the version which gets registered. There are ways around this by launching from eclipse, but the output will go to the console and is only flushed when Blender is closed. So put the break points on the installed version, once they are hit, eclipse will automatically open the file and you can debug away.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite comprehensive instructions for setting up blender and eclipse for debugging.
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Z0r/PyDevAndProfiling

While this is for blenders game engine, much of it applies to regular blender.